# How to properly destruct a PHP singleton instance?

Tags: php, singleton, destructor

**I try to destruct the only instance of my singleton** but can't get it working.

I know I'm supposed to not call the destructor explicitly and **I should set to null any var containing the instance so the destructor is called automagically**.

The thing is that I don't exactly control the multiple vars that store this instance... So I can't set them all to null :(

Now should I call a destructor from inside the class like a `public kill()` method calling `$this->__destruct();`?

I worked out a workaround but I'm not satisfied with dirty ways.
Do you know what is the best practice to do it?

Here is the simplified code I use:

```
<?php
Class MySingleton
{
    private static $instance= null;

    /**
     * Class constructor.
     */
    private function __construct()
    {
        ...
    }

    /**
     * Get the only instance of this class.
     *
     * @return the only instance of this class.
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) self::$instance = new self();
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Class destructor.
     */
    public function __destruct()
    {
        debug('destructing instance of '.__CLASS__.'.');
        debug($this);
    }
}
?>
```

and to get/create the instance I do : `$myObject = MySingleton::getInstance();`

Thank you for your precious advice! ;)

Comment: I haven't seen many occasions in which a mandatory destruct had a decent logical background. What is the reason you want to do this?

Comment: This singleton is a Where instance called by a Query instance in a database context.
The Where clause must be deleted at the end of a query not to be added to a future query.
The Where is a singleton to force user to make only one where clause per query.